# How to send In-App SMS in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

M working on as messenger App .
i want to sent automatically sms on my client  as a verification code and user can use that code as a verification code ..
Can any one help me how to sent sms automatically on my client

Ex.

If user click on register at that time he/she will get conformation sms automatically from iphone client .
That what i need to implement ..

Thanks

Comment: You can either use MFMessageComposeViewController with prefilled information like phone number, msg body etc.. or u can also send background sms if u wish, without actually notifying the user that an sms is being sent using some sms webservice....But i dunno whether apple would approve apps with this kind of sms functionality....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the extension for your question regarding Encoding/Decoding:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Base64 : NSObject {

}

+ (void) initialize;

+ (NSString*) encode:(const uint8_t*) input length:(NSInteger) length;

+ (NSString*) encode:(NSData*) rawBytes;

+ (NSData*) decode:(const char*) string length:(NSInteger) inputLength;

+ (NSData*) decode:(NSString*) string;

@end




#import "Base64.h"


@implementation Base64

#define ArrayLength(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))


static char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
static char decodingTable[128];

+ (void) initialize {
    if (self == [Base64 class]) {
        memset(decodingTable, 0, ArrayLength(decodingTable));
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < ArrayLength(encodingTable); i++) {
            decodingTable[encodingTable[i]] = i;
        }
    }
}


+ (NSString*) encode:(const uint8_t*) input length:(NSInteger) length {
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[index + 0] =                    encodingTable[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 1] =                    encodingTable[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? encodingTable[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? encodingTable[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}


+ (NSString*) encode:(NSData*) rawBytes {
    return [self encode:(const uint8_t*) rawBytes.bytes length:rawBytes.length];
}


+ (NSData*) decode:(const char*) string length:(NSInteger) inputLength {
    if ((string == NULL) || (inputLength % 4 != 0)) {
        return nil;
    }

    while (inputLength > 0 && string[inputLength - 1] == '=') {
        inputLength--;
    }

    NSInteger outputLength = inputLength * 3 / 4;
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:outputLength];
    uint8_t* output = data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger inputPoint = 0;
    NSInteger outputPoint = 0;
    while (inputPoint < inputLength) {
        char i0 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i1 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i2 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A'; /* 'A' will decode to \0 */
        char i3 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A';

        output[outputPoint++] = (decodingTable[i0] << 2) | (decodingTable[i1] >> 4);
        if (outputPoint < outputLength) {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i1] & 0xf) << 4) | (decodingTable[i2] >> 2);
        }
        if (outputPoint < outputLength) {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i2] & 0x3) << 6) | decodingTable[i3];
        }
    }

    return data;
}


+ (NSData*) decode:(NSString*) string {
    return [self decode:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] length:string.length];
}

@end
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ya thanks .. now what about sending validation number using SMS API for ios .. I dont knw hoe to do that can u help me by code ??

Answer (score 3):

You can't send an SMS automatically from iOS, you can present the user with the SMS view and pre fill the SMS body.

You will find more on how the use the MFMessageComposeViewController here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (void) sendSMSCode:(NSString *)smsCode {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [viewController setBody:smsCode];
    // Replace with the number to send the SMS so
    [viewController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"+123456789"]];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release], viewController = nil;
}

#pragma mark - MFMessageComposeViewController methods

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultFailed) {
             // handle the error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..I have been there but m not getting any example .. i need a reference example .. and ya automatically means it just pop up a Security code for verification ...Do u have code like that ....

Comment: thanks for code Man .. but still its not working .. Can u help me how can i encode and decode number which is enter by client in registration form . Help me in that ...

Comment: I want to encode mobile number in 5 digit and then want to decode in the same number on button click event .. Did u get that ?

Comment: Look i have a number of 10 digit .. now i want to generate 5 digit number from that with any symbol like (*,#) and then also i want to decode that number in original 10 digit number .. can u help me in that ?? now u get it ??

Comment: That has nothing to do with your first question and the answer, please create an new question for this. That is how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a in-App SMS is very similar to in-App email, but with some little differences. Use MessageUI Framework for sending in-App SMS.

```
-(IBAction) sendInAppSMS:(id) sender
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Hello from Mugunth";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i have try this code ..but it shows error ..and not working .. Do u know how to Encode and decode a number (mobile number ) in iPhone parametrically .. Do u have code for that ??

Comment: This is not working .. I have made an another file for this . and i am executing it in another file ... can u tell me how can i access this function ??  I have made this function in Smsmanager.m and i am using it in another file on button click event ... like [smsmanager sendInAppSMS ] but it shows error .. wht i need to write with sendInAppSMS ??

Comment: you just tell me what you want to do in simple steps after that i'll able to reply you properly sorry for late reply ...